# Akka Streams filter & group by on a collection of keys

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I have a stream of

```
case class Msg(keys: Seq[Char], value: String)
```

Now I want to filter for a subset of keys e.g. 
`val filterKeys = Set[Char]('k','f','c')` and `Filter(k.exists(filterKeys.contains)))`
And then split these so certain keys are processed by different flows and then merged back together at the end;

```
                                 /-key=k-> f1 --\
Source[Msg] ~> Filter ~> router |--key=f-> f2 ----> Merge --> f4
                                 \-key=c-> f3 --/
```

How should I go about doing this?

`FlexiRoute` in the old way seemed like a good way to go but in the new API I'm guessing I want to either make a custom `GraphStage` or create my own graph from the DSL as I see no way to do this through the built-in stages..?

Answer (score 4):

**Small Key Set Solution**

If your key set is small, and immutable, then a combination of broadcast and filter would probably be the easiest implementation to understand.  You first need to define the filter that you described:

```
def goodKeys(keySet : Set[Char]) = Flow[Msg] filter (_.keys exists keySet.contains)
```

This can then feed a broadcaster as described [in the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html#Constructing_Graphs).  All `Msg` values with good keys will be broadcasted to each of three filters, and each filter will only allow a particular key:

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val source : Source[Msg] = ???

  val goodKeyFilter = goodKeys(Set('k','f','c'))

  val bcast = builder.add(BroadCast[Msg](3))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Msg](3))

  val kKey = goodKeys(Set('k'))
  val fKey = goodKeys(Set('f'))
  val cKey = goodKeys(Set('c'))

  //as described in the question
  val f1 : Flow[Msg, Msg, _] = ???
  val f2 : Flow[Msg, Msg, _] = ???
  val f3 : Flow[Msg, Msg, _] = ???

  val f4 : Sink[Msg,_] = ???

  source ~> goodKeyFilter ~> bcast ~> kKey ~> f1 ~> merge ~> f4
                             bcast ~> fKey ~> f2 ~> merge
                             bcast ~> cKey ~> f3 ~> merge
```

**Large Key Set Solution**

If you key set is large, then groupBy is better.  Suppose you have a `Map` of keys to functions:

```
//e.g. 'k' -> f1
val keyFuncs : Map[Set[Char], (Msg) => Msg]
```

This map can be used with the groupBy function:

```
source
  .via(goodKeys(Set('k','f','c'))
  .groupBy(keyFuncs.size, _.keys)
  .map(keyFuncs(_.keys)) //apply one of f1,f2,f3 to the Msg
  .mergeSubstreams
```